# Spring MVC absolute URL problem

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc

**Background**

I am developing an application (with `Spring MVC`) with its base path as:

```
http://localhost:8080/myapplication/
```

I have a stylesheet `/css/style.css` that I am trying to refer with `absolute path` in a JSP as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection">
```

**Problem**

The stylesheet never loads in the browser. When I follow the stylesheet link through browser's *view source* feature, the link appears to be:

```
http://localhost:8080/css/style.css
```

Which should have had been:

```
http://localhost:8080/myapplication/css/style.css
```

I used to fix this issue with `html:rewrite` tag while working with `Struts`. Is there any equivalent tag/technique in `Spring MVC`?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use the JSTL c:url tag.

```
<c:url value="/css/style.css" var="url" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${url}" type="text/css" media="screen, projection">
```

You can also use the pageContext to prefix the context path.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection">
```

Comment: To avoid cluttering all links with `${pageContext.request.contextPath}`, make use of `<base>` tag.