# How to serve static content from tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a directory containing a number of static file (*.png, *.css, etc).
I thought (mistakenly perhaps) that just creating a directory in my application's WEB-INF file would suffice and I would be able to access the files by just referring to them by name:
Ex:

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/styles.css" type="text/css">
```

My directory structure is as follows:

```
+WEB-INF
   |
   +---static
       |
       +--styles.css
       +--header.png
```

My web.xml is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
version="2.4">
<display-name>myapp</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:com/example/myapp/spring/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            com.example.myapp.ContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!--  
        There are three means to configure Wickets configuration mode and they are
        tested in the order given. 
        1) A system property: -Dwicket.configuration
        2) servlet specific <init-param>
        3) context specific <context-param>
        The value might be either "development" (reloading when templates change)
        or "deployment". If no configuration is found, "development" is the default.
    -->

    <filter>
        <filter-name>wicket.myapp</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>applicationFactoryClassName</param-name>
            <param-value>org.apache.wicket.spring.SpringWebApplicationFactory</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>wicket.session</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.servlet.WicketSessionFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>filterName</param-name>
            <param-value>wicket.myapp</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>wicket.myapp</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>wicket.session</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/servlet/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

But....
This doesn't work I just get a 404 - file not found when attempting to access the resources contained in the "static" directory. Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Don't put them into WEB-INF, that folder is for the stuff that you do *not* want to have directly served.

Put it next to WEB-INF

```
+- WEB-INF
+- static
```

Comment: What do you mean by open? If you really need to access it as a file, you can ask your servlet container for the real file system path.

Comment: @PhilipRego Even if you can (not sure if all servlet containers will allow it), you really should not be writing inside of your webapp directory. The whole point of a WAR is that you have a stateless deployment unit that you can just replace with a later version. Much better to write any data to the filesystem outside of your webapp root (or even shared storage or a database).

Comment: Include files in the WAR at build/deploy-time: Of course. That is what a WAR is for.  But you should not be writing to files at runtime.

Comment: It is very common to have a consistent location like `/var/lib/myapplication/data`. Of course, these days, where you tend to need to scala up across multiple machines and be fault-tolerated about it, dedicated storage systems are taking over from writing to files directly.

Comment: @PhilipRego: The `static` folder next to `WEB-INF` is still within the web application content root. It should appear within the normal URL space that has been assigned to the application (for example `https://myserver/myapp/static` )

Answer (score 5):

The files should not be inside WEB-INF.  They must be placed directly inside your web-applications directory or WAR file.

Look at my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521606/spring-mvc-absolute-url-problem/2521611#2521611) for including the context path before your static resources.

Answer (score 3):

WEB-INF is a protected directory.  They must be placed in or in a subdirectory in the top level web app directory.

Answer (score 0):

The mapping between the URL route and the path in the filesystem must be defined in the server.xml (in the conf directory or your Tomcat server).

In the Host element of your web application in the server.xml file, add something like this:

```
<Context docBase="[filesystem path]" path="[webapp route]" />
```

For example:

```
  <Host appBase="webapps"
           autoDeploy="false" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true"
           xmlNamespaceAware="false" xmlValidation="false">
    ...
    <Context docBase="/home/stuff" path="/static" />
  </Host>
```

You can then access your directory by the URL `http://<your domain>/static`

Note that your directory can be anywhere you want in your filesystem, which is usually convenient.

You can find more info [here](https://www.moreofless.co.uk/static-content-web-pages-images-tomcat-outside-war). That's where I got the example.