# Is it possible to use apache tomcat server as a http file server >

Tags: apache, tomcat

I have installed apache tomcat server on my machine for hosting some servlets. Now I want to put some files on this server so that user can download these files straight away. My question is is it possible to do this ? I mean can apache tomcat server act as a http server as well ? If yes, in which directory in tomcat server I should put these files ?

Please help,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to serve static content from tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523262/how-to-serve-static-content-from-tomcat)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several pointers (from Google):

http://denis-zhdanov.blogspot.com/2009/08/configure-tomcat-static-content.html

Stackoverflow: [How to serve static content from tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523262/how-to-serve-static-content-from-tomcat)

Comment: In case that link ever goes dead, this worked for me: I have Tomcat's ROOT app in `/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/`. If I access `<VPS_ip>:<Tomcat_port>`, I get the "It works!" page. I created a `static` folder inside the `ROOT` folder, placed files inside and was able to access them from `<VPS_ip>:<Tomcat_port>/static/file_name`. This despite several settings that broke some other more or less related things.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the file listing in conf/web.xml and then delete all the files in webapps/root directory and replace it with the files you want to transfer.

The below link could be helpful

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pJPOBKLYZYY