# Tomcat7 how to serve static files with Expires HTTP header

Tags: java, caching, tomcat, tomcat7

I have a group of static files (mainly the static files, including css and images, that make up the [ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs) JavaScript framework). This group of static files *rarely changes* and therefore I decided *NOT* to include them within the items in the web application's war file. (I.e. I didn't follow the approach recommended by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523262/how-to-serve-static-content-from-tomcat).)

Right now I serve all these static files under `/extjs` by having the following [Context container](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html) defined in `server.xml`:

```
<Context docBase="/path/to/extjs-4.1.1" path="/extjs" />
```

That "works" so far; still if anyone is able to suggest a better approach please do.

**However I can't find a way to add `expires` HTTP headers to files served by this context.**

Any idea how to configure Tomcat7 in this respect?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear that Tomcat's default servlet (`org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet`) has a way to do this.

The easiest thing to do would be to create a servlet filter that simply adds the HTTP headers you need to every request. Since the `<context>` defines a webapp, you can add a `WEB-INF/web.xml` file to `/extjs` and load your filter there. Since /extjs is a separate context, your 'real' application won't be affected.

Comment: So what you recommend is that I put a `WEB-INF/web.xml` in the static files' root directory? Right now the static files are "ignorant" of any server-side stuff and I would like to keep them as such.

Comment: Yes, that's the only solution I can think of.