# Spring MVC and nginx dyamic url mapping

Tags: spring-mvc, nginx

I am not sure what the correct phrasing to use. So, I will describe what i have done and desire to do.

I will define what I have on my filesystem under tomcat.

```
1. domainname.com/webapp1 (where webapp1 is the actual folder name being used on the file system)

2. domainname2.com/webapp2 is the url being mapped by nginx to #1
```

This works for the first page.

However, once I start interacting with the webapp2 and dishing up additional views the url resorts to domainname2.com/webapp1

notice that the mapping does not maintain the desired webapp2 ?

**What is the problem here?  How can I fix this?**

Answer (score 0):

I think my answer might be answered at [Spring mvc tomcat application deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13521542/spring-mvc-tomcat-application-deploy)  I will need to test that out and verify.

Comment: This does not work for me.  When my Controller returns a View it still uses the name of the folder as seen in tomcat, namely webapp1